# Deploying rails app to heroku failure -> Bundle is locked to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paas

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to heroku. I'm having an issue with a gem called feeSuggest (I created this myself). It's a simple gem, that takes in a number, and print out a statement based on that.

This is my build log

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       The git source `git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Your bundle is locked to feeSuggest (0.0.0), but that version could not be found
       in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
       that means the author of feeSuggest (0.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to
       update your bundle to a different version of feeSuggest (0.0.0) that hasn't been
       removed in order to install.
       Bundler Output: The git source `git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Your bundle is locked to feeSuggest (0.0.0), but that version could not be found
       in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,
       that means the author of feeSuggest (0.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to
       update your bundle to a different version of feeSuggest (0.0.0) that hasn't been
       removed in order to install.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Where is your gem hosted? It seems `bundler` can't find it.

Comment: I just create that and the gem spec locally on cloud 9 ide. I didn't actually host it anywhere?

Comment: The `Gemfile` in your main app needs to point to some place (a `source`) where the gem can be found.